# Convert result of inet_ntop to string

Tags: c++, string, sockets, inet-ntop

How can I convert the return of the function `inet_ntop` (const char *) to `string`?

The code:

```
string ip = inet_ntop(b->ifa_addr->sa_family,tempAddrPtr,addressOutputBuffer, sizeof(addressOutputBuffer));
```

always results with segfault...

```
struct ifaddrs *a;
void *tempAddrPtr = NULL;
struct ifaddrs *b;
char addressOutputBuffer[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
int i=0;
i=getifaddrs(&a);
cout << i;
b=a;
cout << name;
for (b = a; b; b = b->ifa_next) {
        cout << b->ifa_name;

        if(b->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET)
            tempAddrPtr = &((struct sockaddr_in *)b->ifa_addr)->sin_addr;
          else
            tempAddrPtr = &((struct sockaddr_in6 *)b->ifa_addr)->sin6_addr;
        printf(" Internet Address:  %s \n",
                     inet_ntop(b->ifa_addr->sa_family,
                               tempAddrPtr,
                               addressOutputBuffer,
                               sizeof(addressOutputBuffer)));
                     string ip = inet_ntop(b->ifa_addr->sa_family,tempAddrPtr,addressOutputBuffer, sizeof(addressOutputBuffer));

}
freeifaddrs(a);
```

Comment: Show us the code that sets up the call to `inet_ntop`. Most important is how `addressOutputBuffer` is allocated and how that variable gets its value.

Comment: You're saying the first `inet_ntop` works fine and the second one faults?

Answer (score 0):

inet_ntop returns char*, string ip object will be generated correctly if your inet_ntop returns. The abrupt part is inet_ntop parameters, parameter with pointers.

some debug hints:

```
1. check b is null or not
2. tempAddrPtr is valid or not
3. addressOutputBuffer is valid or not
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is your casting:

```
if(b->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET)
    tempAddrPtr = &((struct sockaddr_in *)b->ifa_addr)->sin_addr;
else
    tempAddrPtr = &((struct sockaddr_in6 *)b->ifa_addr)->sin6_addr;
```

Should be:

```
tempAddrPtr = &(reinterpret_cast<struct sockaddr_in*>(b->ifa_addr)->sin_addr);
tempAddrPtr = &(reinterpret_cast<struct sockaddr_in6*>(b->ifa_addr)->sin_addr);
```

or C:

```
tempAddrPtr = &((struct sockaddr_in*)(b->ifa_addr)->sin_addr);
tempAddrPtr = &((struct sockaddr_in6*)(b->ifa_addr)->sin_addr);
```